# Plot a graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, windows-7, numpy, matplotlib, networkx

I try to plot a simple graph in `networkx`, but this error message appears:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 6 but this version of numpy is 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\project\awk\gg.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "D:\programs\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "D:\programs\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "D:\programs\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 7, in <module>
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "D:\programs\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you plot simple graphs, independently of networkx?

Comment: Can you import numpy?

Comment: please edit the tags to point at the right version of windows.

Comment: How did you install NetworkX, and how did you install Numpy? Are you sure that you don't have Matplotlib already installed?

Comment: I tried many ways. But I forgot it. But If you tell from start it would be easy for me. I want to draw some social network analysis graphs in networkx. Thats why I'm asking this question

Comment: NetworkX isn't the tool for large maps such as social network dumps. And if don't understand your environment you won't go far, just by reusing code, not meant for beginners that aren't even familiar with Python. No need for rush, take it slowly

Comment: how we plot independently in networkx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You downloaded a binary version of `matplotlib` linked/compiled against a newer version of `numpy` than you have installed.

Either upgrade your `numpy` installation, find a version of `matplotlib` compiled against your version of `numpy`, or build `matplotlib` from the source.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200137/installing-numpy-on-64bit-windows-7-with-python-2-7-3

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the API mismatch as stated in the error message. First of all use pip to uninstall numpy.

```
     pip uninstall numpy
```

Then get the latest binary installer for numpy and matplotlib from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) selecting your version of python and windows 32 or 64 bit. Then install it as normal software installer. Make sure it finds your version of python during the installation. This is it !!