# ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-dateutil

I have successfully installed matplotlib with python 2.6 on x64 Windows7. When I try to import matplotlib, it shows the following error. I have also installed numpy following this link: [Installing Numpy on 64bit Windows 7 with Python 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200137/installing-numpy-on-64bit-windows-7-with-python-2-7-3)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil")
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

How can I make it work?

I installed matplotlib-1.3.0.win-amd64-py2.6.exe from http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html

Comment: install `dateutil`.  What version of `mpl` are you using?  There was recently change in how `mpl` deals with external dependencies (shipping them vs installing them).  Please include details of _exactly_ how you installed `mpl`.

Comment: Did you follow the directions [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html)?

Comment: I had a similar issue where I wanted to use matplotlib together with PySide instead of PyQt and that also changed the import which are needed. However by default the backend matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg is PyQt, for PySide it needs to be changed (for example in matplotlibrc).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here's a list of the programs you can install on windows:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

And you'll need the following dependencies:
Requires numpy, dateutil, pytz, pyparsing, six

Comment: On Os X, `sudo pip install numpy python-dateutil pytz pyparsing six --force-reinstall --upgrade` did it for me, thanks :)

Comment: This list of binaries has really made my life easy using python on Win7 64 bit!

Comment: On windows, you skip the sudo part...  just open cmd and do...  pip install numpy python-dateutil pytz pyparsing six

Answer (score 56):

You're probably looking for:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: Ah, `python-dateutil`, not `dateutil`... I think that was my problem.