# ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror, python-dateutil

Am new to progamming and Python, i keep getting the error below when i run my program. Someone advised i should use pip to solve it. But cant pip get installed using the cmd. Though i suceeded using Powershell but still cant make it work. How do i solve this, any tips will go along way. Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from satmc import satmc
  File "C:\Python27\starb_models_grid1\satmc.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil")
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

Am using version 2.7.3

Comment: $ sudo pip install python-dateutil ( It's duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280436/importerror-matplotlib-requires-dateutil )

Answer (score 2):

You need to install various packages to get `numpy` working correctly.

1. libsvm-3.17.win32-py2.7
2. pyparsing-2.0.1.win32-py2.7
3. python-dateutil-2.2.win32-py2.7
4. pytz-2013.9.win32-py2.7
5. six-1.5.2.win32-py2.7
6. scipy-0.13.3.win32-py2.7
7. numpy-MKL-1.8.0.win32-py2.7
8. Matplotlib

Download all the binaries from this [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and install and then you will have a working numpy installation.

Comment: You are missing `dateutil`. That is literally exactly what your error message means.

Comment: @ajkumar25, do you have link where i can get CosmoloPy executable?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Answer (score 1):

The error states that you are missing Dateutil.

This could mean that you did not install *Dateutil* with `pip install python-dateutil` or your way to install Python modules. But if you did your pip install and still get the same error it could also mean that  DateUtil is installed in a folder where your Python distribution does not expect it.

In my case (Mac OSX) I installed pip with Brew http://brew.sh/.  That pip will install the modules in: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

However the standard Mac OSX Python distribution will look for modules in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Your folders could be different of course, but you can check where Python looks for modules with:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Check this and see if one of the directories in the list contains the directory where dateutil is installed.
If not add a PYTHONPATH environment variable: Like: `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` or the folder where your dateutil is installed

Answer (score 0):

I did pip install python-dateutil, but kept getting the same error. I got past that error by installing from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-dateutil
Look for the Matplotlib section and install the dependencies you don't have.
Matplotlib is a 2D plotting library.
Requires numpy, dateutil, pytz, pyparsing, six, setuptools, and optionally pillow, pycairo, tornado, wxpython, pyside, pyqt4, ghostscript, miktex, ffmpeg, mencoder, avconv, or imagemagick.