# ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil- python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, python-dateutil

I get this error when i try to import matplotlib. I have installed matplotlib.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>     
   import matplotlib   
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>     
   raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil") 
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: did you installed matplotlib using pip?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280436/importerror-matplotlib-requires-dateutil)

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` depends on `dateutil`

On **Linux** you can install it using

`pip install python-dateutil`

You can reinstall them forcefully using

`pip install python-dateutil --force-reinstall --upgrade`

To install `pip` on windows get the script [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) from here. Then on cmd run

`python get-pip.py`

Comment: I work on windows and i have tried all of it multiple times. thank you @radbrawler

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed .?

Comment: Firstly it asks for dateutil. I have the .whl file of dateutil. Could you help me to install that .whl file so that matplotlib works?

Comment: I do have pip installed as well as upgraded

Comment: to install `*.whl` files `pip install xyz.whl` see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Comment: I have installed numPy and sciPy, so my pip works perfectly. I just need to Install matplotlib. And i get an error that i require dateutil. So how to go about with that?

Comment: I am not using anaconda so i need to specify the path. And i did try but it doesn't work

Comment: I got the response as - No module named statlib

Comment: pip install python-dateutil : gives invalid syntax

Comment: you are running it on python interpreter. Run it on windows cmd.