# conda update numpy to 1.8.x for 64-bit windows

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, spyder

I'm using a 64-bit machine with Spyder by Anaconda and want to upgrade numpy from 1.7.1 to 1.8.x. But when I use this command:

```
conda update numpy
```

I get the following message:

[image]

In other words, the same old version 1.7.1. Why is this? I want the latest numpy.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this thread:

[Installing Numpy on 64bit Windows 7 with Python 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200137/installing-numpy-on-64bit-windows-7-with-python-2-7-3)

There was an answer saying:

> But you need to modify your environment variable PATH, so that the
>   anaconda folder is before the original Python folder.

I've actually got two anaconda systems on my machine a 32-bit path and the path to the 64-bit environment that I use, so I deleted the path to 32-bit anaconda and put the Python27 path after the 64-bit anaconda path, and now when I try to update numpy, it works, to 1.8.x!