# How do I install Numpy for Python 2.7 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I am trying to install numpy for python 2.7, I've downloaded the zip, unzipped it and was expecting a Windows download file (.exe), but there isn't one. 
Which of these files do I use to install it? 
I tried running the setup.py file but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Thanks!!!

Comment: May interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200137/installing-numpy-on-64bit-windows-7-with-python-2-7-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is .exe file in SourceForge. This is this link below:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.1/numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was trying to find.

Comment: You can also marked this reply as an answer to your question.

Comment: this fails with miniconda on win10

Answer (score 2):

Python on Windows, including rather complex science/math/statistics package builds? It should just work? Seriously, use a third-party distribution! There are plenty and they only exist as of the hassle you were observing.

While the other two answers are "okay", it would recommend another approach. Especially for the common Windows user the following approach is easy to maintain and easy to reproduce.

Let me quote from the SciPy website:

> For most users, especially on Windows and Mac, the easiest way to
>   install the packages of the SciPy stack is to download one of these
>   Python distributions, which includes all the key packages:

[a list of Python distributions]

As you can see, people having experience with this topic tend to recommend using a third-party Python distribution.

I have so far used [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads), but [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) also appears to be a well-maintained project.

Whichever you take: it comes as a nice Windows installer and will give you a seamless Python experience.

Comment: I'm using Anaconda on a couple of Windows machines and I'm happy with it.

Comment: I'm going to try this asap. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a very well maintained list of Python Libraries (including numpy) for Windows at this Homepage: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

Wasted a lot of time trying to install on Windows from various binaries and installers, which all seemed to install a broken version, until I found that this worked: navigate to the python install directory and do `python .\site-packages\pip install numpy`