# pip command does nothing

Tags: python, pip

I just installed Python 2.7.10 on windows 10.
I have added my python and `pip` directory to my PATH like so:

[image]

My Scripts folder looks like this:

[image]

My problem is, when I type in "pip" in command prompt and press enter absolutely nothing happens, even if I wait several minutes. If I remove the Scripts directory from the PATH variable I just get the error message like "pip not recognized as internal or external command". Python works fine. I have also tried to reinstall both pip and Python but the same problem occurs. 
So, does anyone have any idea about why pip does not do anything?

**Edit: ** when I say it does not do anything, I mean the cmd "hangs", like if it is waiting for something to happen. The cursor just keeps on blinking.

Comment: can you try python -m pip

Comment: Does the prompt come back or does it hang?

Comment: @SebastianWozny This worked for installing the package cv2, but when I tried to install numpy I get an error that Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. I am going to look into that since I am not familiar with this command.

Comment: Try `pip-3.5` or `pip-2.7`. This is what worked for me on Amazon EC2-Instance e.g., `pip-3.5 install ldap3`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One command that is bound to work is writing:

```
python -m pip install requests
```

This works because you hand off the script invocation to python, which you know works, instead of relying on the `PATH` environment variable of windows, which can be dodgy.

Packages like numpy that require c-extensions to be built, will not work with `pip` unless you have a C Compiler installed on your system. More information can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200137/installing-numpy-on-64bit-windows-7-with-python-2-7-3).

If you are, as you're saying, unfamiliar with the python environment, then let me assure you, you will have a better day by installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

> Anaconda is a completely free Python distribution (including for
>   commercial use and redistribution). It includes more than 300 of the
>   most popular Python packages for science, math, engineering, and data
>   analysis.

Anaconda comes with numpy, of course.

Comment: Ok I see. However, I managed to install numpy by downloading from the unnoficial binaries site, but I will install Anaconda anyways! Tanks!

Comment: Anaconda also comes with matplotlib, scipy, pandas, ipython and spyder. I think working with anaconda on windows is easier than working with python on linux.

Comment: Thanks! I have been trying to solve this for hours and this worked!

Comment: Try `pip-3.5` or `pip-2.7`. This is what worked for me on Amazon EC2-Instance e.g., `pip-3.5 install ldap3`.

Answer (score 4):

After Python including pip at package, pip commands not work sometimes.
Then you can use pip through python like

```
python -m pip <pip commands that you want>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling your virus scanner. If this fixes it, exclude the `C:\Python27\` folder from scanning (at your own risk).

---

I had this same issue: typing `pip` on the command line just puts the cursor on the next line, and nothing happens. I was sure my `PATH` system variable had `C:\Python27\` and `C:\Python27\Scripts\` in it, and I could verify it using `echo %PATH%` on the command line.

I found that I had to disable my virus scanner (Avast). I excluded the `C:\Python27\` from virus scanning, and now everything works. Apparently the scanner is interfering with Python's ability to load the module.

Comment: I waited about five minutes with a blinking cursor, then the script finally started executing in a new window while Avast popped up a "this script may be dangerous, we're doing a 15-second scan" window.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following path or you can also cd to the path and then try pip command, it will work fine.

`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip`

Comment: Thanks for the effort but unfortunately this does not work for me :(

Comment: Have you tried cd C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip and then trying just pip command?

Comment: @AimadAshan Yes I have tried that too. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after uninstalling my antivirus, which was blocking the script. The issue was resolved.