# Trying to implement a jacobian matrix in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I am working on a project that does some simulation and analysis for some buses on a circuit and I am required to implement a jacobian matrix like the one in the picture below in python

[Jacobian matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WILYX.png)

I am still a beginner and i am trying to get some ideas on whats the best way to implement the matrix,i have been reading other posts here and most of them suggest using numpy, which i haven't been able to install ( i have windows 10 64bit). I would appreciate any help !

Comment: I am dealing with a python script that is connected to a simulation software, the script spits out voltage and power values, i have to implement a jacobian matrix that takes those values and does the calculations as the one shown in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find a way to install numpy on Windows if you want to use python it is full of useful methods and I should say essential
check here [Installing Numpy on 64bit Windows 7 with Python 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200137/installing-numpy-on-64bit-windows-7-with-python-2-7-3) it may helps you (even if it's only Windows seven you can actually try).

But if you plan on working with python you should try one of the releases of Linux (ubuntu e.g.) which are easy to install and open source.

For the calculus of the Jacobian matrix you can still implement it "by-hand" which is getting the step of a function with respect to each variable.

Comment: I guess I have no choice, will try to do that thanks